# How do we avoid extra intermediate certificates from herokuapp

Tags: ssl, heroku, ssl-certificate

After searching for several hours I'm finally posting a question.

I have my ssl certificate uploaded to heroku with the SSL addon.Everything works fine and have no issues with the certificates.

However, when I visit http://www.digicert.com/help/index.htm?host=mydomain.com, I see 2 additional certs which I never uploaded onto heroku. I suspect they are the default certs found on heroku.com. 
I later on removed my certs from the server to check if they are really the default one's and to my surprise, I was right.

Now, the question is How do I remove the additional certs from the heroku?

Has anyone experienced this issue before ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can upload the correct chain from your local system and bypass the Heroku client's chain completion with:

```
$ heroku certs:update crt-file key-file --bypass
```

(or `certs:add` for new endpoints.)

The trick is the `--bypass` flag.

**Update:** this is fixed on Heroku's end now. `--bypass` should generally no longer be required.

Comment: I did add my certs with the command above but I keep getting the same extra certs of heroku when I visit  http://www.digicert.com/help/index.htm?host=mydomain.com
This is driving me nuts :(

Comment: can you share the actual domain name in use?

Comment: At this point I'd try getting a new endpoint by doing `certs:remove` first, then `certs:add` again. It'll get you a new endpoint with a different hostname, which means a DNS update. If this is in production, using a low TTL helps. My thinking is that the backend is not processing your updated chain because the head of the chain is the same as the installed cert.

Comment: We had to use the `--bypass` flag to correctly preserve our chain, which contains two additional certs (GeoTrust Global CA signed by Equifax, Equifax root) that are required for [older Android devices](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10807). Without the option, Heroku stripped the two additional certs and caused an SSL error on these devices.

Comment: @PhilCalvin can you open a ticket with heroku and ask that it be routed to me? I'd like to look into the issue you had.